# Convert to Binary

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, hmac

To use the HMAC function:

```
hmac.digest(key, msg, digest)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/hmac.html
The key and msg needs to be in bytes or bytearray object. The key and msg input are generally a string. I cannot find a way to easily convert straight from a string to a the bytes / bytearray object. It seems that you first need to convert to an integer and from there to the byte object. `bin(foo) --> str` 
only converts to its binary representation however, the output of bin(input) is still a string which the HMAC function will not accept. First prize would be to find a function which will convert my msg or key (string) directly to the byte array or bytes object, if not than the process to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the bytes object of a string by calling the encode method of the string. You can provide it the type of encoding or leave it blank and it will use the default encoding.

```py
import hmac
import hashlib
key = "secret key"
message = "this is a secret message"
digest = hmac.digest(key.encode(), message.encode(), hashlib.sha3_256)
print(digest)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
b'\xdb3\xdd\xa3\xc48\xbe%"\x97;\xbf\x90\x84E\xd4\x9e\x89g\x12\x0f\'h\xc1\xc4\x95Si\x90A\xbf\xbc'
```

You can read more about it here https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode. Extract below

> Return an encoded version of the string as a bytes object. Default
>   encoding is 'utf-8'. errors may be given to set a different error
>   handling scheme.